# Linear transformation $f \in L( \mathbb R[t]_{2}, (\mathbb R^{2})^{*})$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let linear transformation $f \in L( \mathbb R[t]_{2}, (\mathbb R^{2})^{*})$ for which $f(p)( {\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\end{bmatrix}})=p(0)\cdot x_{1}+p(1) \cdot x_{2}$ for $p \in \mathbb R[t]_{3},{\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\end{bmatrix}} \in \mathbb R^{2}$. 
>  (a) Find a basis for subspace $ker f$. 
>  (b) Find transformation matrix $f$ in a basis $1,t,t^{2}$ in space $\mathbb R[t]_{2}$ and in the dual base to the base $[1,0]^{T},[0,1]^{T}$ in space $(\mathbb R^{2})^{*}$.

I know how to find transformation matrix but I don't understand how to do it when I have functionals and books are unhelpful to me.
Is there anyone who can tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do as you usually do. Try to represent the image of basis elements of the domain under $f$ in the linear combination of basis elements of the codomain. 
For example: 
$f(1)(x1, x2) =x1+x2=f1(x1, x2)+f2(x1, x2)=(f1+f2)(x1, x2)$ 
This implies $f(1) =f1+f2$, where $f1$ and $f2$ is the dual basis.
Similarly find $f(t)$ and $f(t^2)$ in the linear combination of $f1$ and $f2$.

Comment: Could you help me with (a) also? It seemed to me that I could, but probably not

Comment: If $p(t)=a+bt+ct^2$ would be in $kerf$ then $ax1+(a+b+c)x2=0$ for all $x1, x2 \in {\mathbb R}$ and this would imply $a=0, b=-c$. Hence $kerf$ consists of polynomial of the form $bt-bt^2$.